# Is there any way to convert the fields of raw Sequelize query into camelcase?

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('db', 'userName', 'password',{
    dialect: 'postgres',
  define: {
    underscored: true,
    },
    query: {
        raw: true
    }
});
```

I am using underscored field values for the database and camelCase field values on application level. I am getting the data in correct format using sequelize querying methods but it is causing a problem when I use Raw Sequelize queries with `sequelize.query()` because it returns underscored field name. Is there any way to change this behavior?

Comment: Did you try to quote column names? I.e. `table.column as ColumnName` -> `table.column as "ColumnName"`

Comment: Yes, that works but I have to manually write down all of the required fields so I was looking for an alternative.

Comment: it depends on DBMS not on Sequelize because it's a plain SQL and Sequelize does not modify it at all. Look at your DBMS options to keep column aliases letter case intact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It works.

```
class TheModel extends Sequelize.Model {

}

TheModel.init({
  userId: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER},
  label: {type: DataTypes.STRING},
}, {
  sequelize: sequelize,
  underscored: true,
}

...

TheModel.rawAttributes['userId'].field    // 'user_id'
```